# Does $ \mathcal{R}({C^T})\, \cap\, \mathcal{N}({AY+YA}^T) = \{0\} $ imply $ \mathcal{R}({C^T})\, \cap\, \mathcal{N}({CAY}) = \{0\} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $ \mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{Y}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} >0, \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ Hurwitz, $ \mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \mathrm{rank}(\mathbf{C})=m,\ m \le n $, I want to find whether the condition $ \mathbf{C(AY+YA^T)C^T}=0 $ eventually implies $ \mathbf{CAYC}^T=0 $. Since, $ \mathbf{C}\ne 0 $, and $ \mathbf{AY}\ne \mathbf{-YA}^T \ne 0 $ (because $ \mathbf{Y}>0 $ and $ \mathbf{A} $ is Hurwitz), the only condition which implies $ \mathbf{C(AY+YA^T)C^T}=0 $ is that $ \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{C^T})\, \cap\, \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{AY+YA}^T) = \{0\} $.

Now my question is: does this condition $ \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{C^T})\, \cap\, \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{AY+YA}^T) = \{0\} $ imply $ \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{C^T})\, \cap\, \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{CAY}) = \{0\} $; or in other words: does $ \mathbf{C(AY+YA^T)C^T}=0 \implies \mathbf{CAYC^T}=0 $?

Comment: Control theory is notationally rather ugly.

Comment: The question is about linear algebra. Control theory didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not imply. It may well happen that $AY + YA^T$ is sign indefinite. To find an example choose $A$ Hurwitz (but not diagonal) and pick $Y=I$. Then it is not difficult to find a $1 \times n$ matrix $C$ that results in $C (A + A^T) = 0$.